# How to delete local notifications from tableview in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

In my app I am showing the local notifications in table view.

Here is the code:

```
NSArray *notificationArray=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
UILocalNotification *notif = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];
```

I want to delete selected row from table view, how can I do?

Comment: Please think about what you are tagging this had nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the row...delete from the model.

```
[yourModelArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

EDIT:

Reload your table view:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: or just the cell! `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: What sample code? you have your project, whatever you are facing the problem we answered. And I guess you are having the problem of model data array. instead of directly showing in tablview cell, first add that notif to a model array, then show it on your tableview.

Comment: How to add notification to a model array?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to delete particular local notification, when user taps on particular cell then:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *notificationArray=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notificationToCancel= [notificationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notificationToCancel];
    [yourTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: @ArulKumar: means, if you need to remove notification you can do it like this. If you just need to delete row use the anoop's answer. What is the issue ?